# Adding image to sqlite studio Ionic

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, sqlitestudio

I searched, but found nothing. Is it possible to add an image to sqlite studio? I have a database in my project, and in it I have some tables and columns with products. They all have information, but now I need to add an image to each of them. Is it possible for me to create a new column to per image? Could anyone explain to me in detail what I can do to add an image in the bank and call in my project. I can post my code if need be. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite and storing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935460/sqlite-and-storing-images)

Comment: This question is too broad. What have you tried? sqlite can store blobs.

Comment: I am using sqlite studio to add the information. But I do not know how to insert the image into sqlite studio. in verdaee I do not know if you have how to insert image there.

Comment: Images support was added to SQLiteStudio 3.2.x. Just download most recent version from its home page. Then add BLOB column and edit its value. You will get editor dialog, where you can switch to Image tab and there is button to load image from file into that field.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try, although the sqlite studio website is offline apparently. I'm looking for another way to download or upgrade to the release.

Comment: I was able to install and add the image, but in my application instead of showing the image, I'm getting numbers like: "89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44". Can you tell me how to decrypt it? or what can I do?